# jquery mobile center two buttons inline in the footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I want to be able to align two buttons in the center of my footer in jquery mobile. I have put my code in jsfiddle below: -

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rULKH/100/)

How would I do this, I am nearly there with it.

```
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="option-page"> 
        <div data-role="content"> 

        </div>
        <div id="homeFooter" class="controlsFooter" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
                <div class="center-wrapper" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
                  <a href="#filterPage" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" data-icon="check" data-mini="true">Filter</a>
                </div>

                <div class="center-wrapper" style="float:left;">
                        <form name="actions" action="" method="post">
                                <select name="select-action" id="select-action" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" 
                                data-icon="home" tabindex="-1" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-shadow="false">
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                </select>
                        </form>
                </div><!-- end of center wrap -->
            </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>
```

- Also how do you center buttons and align them together inline. For example the Facebook app Header, icon buttons, left, 3 in the center and 1 on the right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple elements you are only able to center align them next to each other if they are inline or inline-block elements, otherwise you will need to work out the total width of the elements you need to center, whack them in a div of that width and then put margin auto on that div

http://jsfiddle.net/rULKH/101/

In your example I have wrapped your buttons in a div to center them:

```
        <div style="width:150px; margin:auto;">
        <div class="center-wrapper" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
          <a href="#filterPage" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" data-icon="check" data-mini="true">Filter</a>
        </div>

        <div class="center-wrapper" style="float:left;">
                <form name="actions" action="" method="post">
                        <select name="select-action" id="select-action" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" 
                        data-icon="home" tabindex="-1" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-shadow="false">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                        </select>
                </form>
        </div><!-- end of center wrap -->
</div>
```

​